# how to get the SQLCipher password for sqlite database file?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqlcipher

i tried to open sqlite database file with DB browser for sqlite but i faced this window, what password should i type? 
[image]

Comment: If this is a SQLCipher-encrypted database, you use the passphrase that you used to encrypt the database. If this is a plain SQLite database, you should not need a password, so try leaving the field empty. If you encounter problems with this, contact the developers of "DB browser for sqlite".

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the problem is fixed this window appeared to me because the database file is sent by email (go through the network) that is why it asked for a password when I transferred by flash Usb it opens normally

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQLChipher db then use [SQLite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) to open that db [github link it's opensource](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/releases)

[image]

[image]]

> And as far as I know **there’s no way to open a SQLCipher database without knowing the current encryption key**, and to be able to change the encryption key, you need to first open the database.
> So If you find any solution please share to open db without key or any way to get key from encrypted  db.